# Same distribution because of expectation

Tags: probability

If $f$ is a positive function and for $X,Y$ two random variables, $E[f(X)]=E[(f(Y)]$.
Why do we have that $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution ?

I know it is true if $f$ is a real bounded function (I have to admit that I don't know the proof of this or where to find it), but I didn't know for the positive case.

Thank you a lot for the consideration to this post,

Comment: Any function $f$ can be decomposed to $f^{+}(x)=\max(0,f(x))$ and $f^{-}=\max(0,-f(x))$ and note that $f^{+}$ and $f^{-}$ are both non-negative functions. Then $f(x)=f^{+}(x)-f^{-}(x)$. So $E(f(X))=E(f^{+}(X))-E(f^{-}(X))$. So if the equality holds for all non-negative functions, then you also have $E(f(X))=E(f(Y))$ for all functions $f$. And this is obviously stronger than this just holding for real bounded functions. Actually, you only need it for bounded continuous functions.

Comment: You need to say "non constant". Surely the equality is true for $x \mapsto 1$ for any RVs X,Y.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! May I ask you about why it's work too for the "bounded continuous function" case ?

Comment: Because bounded continuous functions approximate indicators of open sets, and a borel probability measure is uniquely determined by the open sets. So if it agrees for any bounded continuous function, it also agrees for the indicator of any open set. Thus it also agrees for the indicator of any borel set. In fact, you can even take it to be lipschitz compactly supported, since this is how you approximate indicators of open sets, but this is mostly just abstract nonsense

Comment: Your question needs quantifiers before it becomes meaningful.  There certainly exist rvs $X$ and $Y$ and functions for which $Ef(X)=Ef(Y)$ but yet $X$ and $Y$ have different distributions.  Stick in a few "for all", "there exist", and so ons, and an occasional "if" and "then", for good measure.  Please.